# Why asp is not recognized in an include file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have an `about.aspx` page which calls an include file (because I want to reuse the file in my other aspx pages as well) like this:

```
<!-- #include virtual ="includeNav/radHours.inc" -->
```

Inside the include file, I have a bunch of HTML/ASP.NET controls. Some of them are:

```
<asp:Label id="lhWP" runat="server" text="White Plains" />
<div id="dvWP" runat="server" style="width: 100%; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px;"></div>
```

I get the following error:

```
Namespace prefix 'asp' not defined
```

Why do I get the error and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Don't use include files. Now we have [UserControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y6wb1a0e(v=vs.100).aspx) and [MasterPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage.aspx) that give us that functionality. I doubt the ASP.NET engine properly parses "include" files, and therefore the raw contents are sent to the client instead of the generated HTML.

Comment: I have a master page already and I am using one line inside the master page for each sub pages: `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" />` and my about.aspx page is the whole featuredcontent. Inside the about.aspx how do I call another page?

Comment: The link I provided explains all of that. Try it out. If you have specific problems, feel free to post them to SO.

Comment: By the way, I'd suggest using the term **ASP.NET** instead of "ASP" to help differentiate this technology from "classic ASP".

Comment: @MarioJVargas Thanks. I just edited it. Great point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a UserControl, then reference it in the **about.aspx** page.

In Visual Studio right-click on your project or a subfolder within it, then point to **Add** and select **New Item...**

Then in the **Add New Item** dialog box select **Web**, then click on **Web Forms User Control** (It may simply say **User Control**). Name it **RadHours.ascx**

Then paste the code from your SSI (server-side include) in the user control. Please note that the `Inherits` property uses the namespace `WebApplication1`. You will need to change this so it matches your namespace scheme. This is for illustration purposes.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RadHours.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.RadHours" %>

<asp:Label id="lhWP" runat="server" text="White Plains" />
<div id="dvWP" runat="server" style="width: 100%; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px;"></div>
```

Then in the **about.aspx** page, place the following line below the `@Page` directive:

```
<%@ Register tagPrefix="uc" tagName="RadHours" src="RadHours.ascx" %>
```

Finally, replace the `#include` directive you used with this:

```
<uc:RadHours ID="radHours" runat="server" />
```

Comment: from the look of it, it seems the UserControl can also have standard HTML tag, which adding a `runat=server` can also be accessed by the code-behind like other aspx controls? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It should be noted that you can register controls in the `web.config` file so you don't have to manually register them on each page you want to use them on. Very helpful if you end up using the control more than once (which is the whole point of making it a control!)

Comment: @SiKni8 Yes, you can think of UserControls as reusable snippets of markup/code. Anything you can do on a page you can do on a UserControl. So you can make your regular HTML controls accessible on the server by adding `runat="server"` to them.

Comment: I can avoid this line `<%@ Register tagPrefix="uc" tagName="RadHours" src="RadHours.ascx" %>` in every page I need to use it in, If I register it in `web.config`?

Comment: @SiKni8 , yes you can access user controls from the code-behind of the referencing page. Treat them as you would any encapsulated class.

Comment: I think this will also fix my "Namespace 'control' cannot be found in current context" errors. I will update you. Thanks!